# tablet doesn't turn on, does it need a backup battery?

Tags: battery, tablet

I would like to know if the tablet needs a backup battery to start (the device does not turn on anymore)

It is an old device.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try holding the on/off switch for about 8 seconds?

Comment: How old is the tablet? When was the battery charged for the also time?